# Largest rectangle covering set bits in a bitmap

Tags: algorithms

I have a 2D bitmap with various shapes (each pixel is either 1 or 0).

How can I find the largest axis-aligned rectangle that covers only set pixels?

Comment: What do you mean by *largest*? In terms of area?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, largest area

Comment: @PålGD 1D is easy, you can just do it in a single O(n) swipe left to right

Comment: Are you ok with an approximation?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'd prefer the global maximum ofc, but I need to do this on about a billion bitmaps of up to 100x100, so if it's significantly faster an approximation might be the better choice

Comment: Here is a simple approximation scheme: (1) Compute the maximum area of a rectangle of height at most $h$, where $h$ is a parameter, by brute force (2) Halve the number of rows by ANDing pairs of rows, solve recursively, and convert the resulting rectangle to the original bitmap by doubling it (3) Choose the best among the two answers.

Comment: You can in linear time compute the number of zeros in the rectangle (0,0) to (i,j). You can use this to query whether (up,left),(down,right) defines a valid rectangle in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in $O(n^3)$ time, for a $n\times n$ bitmap.

Let $A$ denote the image, so $A[i,j]$ is the pixel at coordinates $(i,j)$.

For each pixel $(i,j)$, let $H[i,j]$ denote the height of the column of all-1 pixels below it, i.e., the largest $h$ such that $A[i',j]=1$ for all $i' \in [i,i+h-1]$.

For each pixel $(i,j)$ and each height $h$, let $W[i,j,h]$ denote the width of the rectangle of height $h$ with upper-left corner at $(i,j)$ that has covers only set pixels, i.e., the largest $w$ such that $H[i,j'] \ge h$ for all $j' \in [j,j+w-1]$.

You can compute each element of $H$ in $O(1)$ time using dynamic programming (fill them in from the bottom up).  Also, once you have $H$, you can compute each element of $W$ in $O(1)$ time using dynamic programming (fill them in the right to left).

Finally, once you have $W$, it is trivial to find the largest rectangle, by scanning all of its elements.

In other words, if you have a $n\times n$ bitmap, you can fill in $H$ in $O(n^2)$ time and fill in $W$ in $O(n^3)$ time, and then you can find the largest rectangle in $O(n^3)$ time.  So, this gives an $O(n^3)$ time algorithm.  That is an improvement over [Pål GD's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146362/largest-rectangle-covering-set-bits-in-a-bitmap#comment308942_146362), which takes $O(n^4)$ time.

If the bitmap is rectangular rather than square, you can use the same algorithm.  I suggest you transpose it first if it is taller than it is wide; that way you will have fewer values of $h$ to iterate over.  In this way, if you have a $m\times n$ bitmap, the running time will be $O(\min(mn^2,m^2n))$.